# Can't find the paste function called 'Match Destination formation'

Tags: microsoft-excel, paste

I cannot see the Paste Special option f 'Match Destination formating' in Exce l 2010.  I use this when subtotalling and then copying out data to another worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The option you need is called Paste Values.